# How to retrieve 'Unit System' Metric(Kg, cm)/Imperial(Pound, Inch) of the Shop

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

Wanted to know the way to fetch the 'Unit System' that is set for the Shop. A shop sets the unit system from General Settings,  Adjust your standards and formats.

I checked the Shop, Cart, Order API calls, but it does not have this info. Shop call does have `currency` info but not the unit system information. What is the way to fetch the Shops Unit System using API calls?

Regards,

Nilesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't available through the API at the moment, but may be added in the future. FYI all weights are in grams.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes I see all weights are in grams, I want to Sync my app account details with ones configured on Shopify and use that info in some way. Btw, are you from Shopify Tech team?

Comment: I am a developer at Shopify, on the API and Integrations team specifically. We'll look into exposing that on the Shop object, but at the moment it isn't available.

Comment: Thanks John, I wanted to hear directly from someone Shopify API team, hence confirmed.